# Computing the Detail Coeffiecients without Downsampling

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, signal-processing, wavelet

The wavelet transform allows us to compute the detail coeffiecients of a signal or image. It also down-samples the image at each decomposition level.

I want to compute the detail coefficients without downsampling. I want to use the low pass filter, G, to extract the detail coefficients like a Quadrature Mirror Filter describes minus the down sampling. However, I only have this filter in 1D: `[-1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)]`

As I understand, I can first apply G to the rows of the image and then to the columns. How can i perform this multiplication in Numpy? My image has a size of `768x768`.

Comment: what's the size of this 1D array? `[-1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)]
`

Comment: @kmario23 `(2,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then we can leverage broadcasting to do this but before that we have to tile our initial filter to match one of the dimensions of our image. And luckily, the image here is a square image. So, a lot of things become easier:

```
In [70]: filter_ = np.array([-1/np.sqrt(2), 1/np.sqrt(2)])

In [71]: filter_
Out[71]: array([-0.70710678,  0.70710678])

# tile the initial array to match the dimensions of image
In [72]: filter_1d = np.tile(filter_, 768//2)

In [73]: filter_1d.shape
Out[73]: (768,)

In [74]: img = np.random.random_sample((768, 768))

# apply the filter on the image
In [76]: filtered = np.multiply(img, filter_1d)

In [77]: filtered.shape
Out[77]: (768, 768)
```

Comment: In which direction is this multiplied? Rows or Columns?

Comment: Since we tile it, this would be broadcasted along second dimension. However, the multiplication is element-wise